# Break loop and return in Racket Scheme

Tags: function, loops, scheme, return, racket

I'm trying to find the first missing key in a hash table, that should contain keys [1 ... N], using Scheme.

So far, I have the following code:

```
(define (find-missing n ht)
  (define c 1)

  (let forVertices ()
    (cond (not (hash-has-key? ht c))
      (c)
    )

    (set! c (+ c 1))
    (when (>= n c) (forVertices))
  )
)
```

When I execute the function to test it, nothing is returned. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of problems with the parentheses, and the `else` case is missing. This should fix the mistakes:

```
(define (find-missing n ht)
  (define c 1)
  (let forVertices ()
    (cond ((not (hash-has-key? ht c))
           c)
          (else
           (set! c (+ c 1))
           (when (>= n c)
             (forVertices))))))
```

… But you should be aware that the way you wrote the procedure is not idiomatic, at all. In general, in Scheme you should avoid mutating state (the `set!` operation), you can write an equivalent procedure by correctly setting up the recursion and passing the right parameters. Also, it's a good idea to return something whenever the recursion exits (for instance: `#f`), otherwise your procedure will return `#<void>` if there are no keys missing. Here, this is what I mean:

```
(define (find-missing n ht)
  (let forVertices ((c 1))
    (cond ((> c n) #f)
          ((not (hash-has-key? ht c)) c)
          (else (forVertices (+ c 1))))))
```